# Vb.net Adding combobox column datagrid view data to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

So I am using the advanced datagrid view and the filtering/sorting only works if the data is in a datatable however I am also using combobox columns and need to filter on them also but I don't know how to add the combobox data to the table and the data is not from a database it's just a string collection can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: I've never used that custom control but I believe that it should be exactly the same as a standard `DataGridView` for this specific purpose. In that case, [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) should provide all the information you need about adding and binding a combo box column.

Comment: I used this it worked
https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview/issues/122

Comment: You should not leave a resolved issue unanswered. Please provide an answer that will help others - that might contain the link but also a full explanation of what you actually did - or delete the question.